# redundant volatile in cheap read-write lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

Brian Goetz in his article from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/

uses the example pasted below as a cheap read-write lock. My question is that if the int variable value is not declared volatile then would it make a difference? My understanding is that since the writes to value are done within a synchronized block so latest value will be visible to other threads any way and therefore declaring it volatile is redundant. Please clarify?

```
@ThreadSafe
public class CheesyCounter {
// Employs the cheap read-write lock trick
// All mutative operations MUST be done with the 'this' lock held
@GuardedBy("this") private volatile int value;

public int getValue() { return value; }

public synchronized int increment() {
    return value++;
}
```

}

Comment: `getValue` isn't synchronized.

Comment: `getValue()` could return stale value because it is not synchronized thus there is no happens-before relation between `increment()` and `getValue()` without `volatile`

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that since the writes to value are done within a synchronized block so latest value will be visible to other threads any way

This is incorrect.  Generally, there is no guarantee that other threads "see" changes to variables as soon as the change is made.  A thread may see a stale value for a changed variable because, e.g. the thread sees the value really in a register instead of main memory.

A `volatile` variable establishes "happens-before" semantics.  The [JLS, section 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), states:

> Two actions can be ordered by a *happens-before* relationship. If one action *happens-before* another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> - A write to a `volatile` field (§8.3.1.4) *happens-before* every subsequent read of that field.

The [JLS, Section 8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4):

> A field may be declared `volatile`, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable (§17.4).

The reason that the field must be `volatile` is that even though the read is atomic, it needs to ensure that the value is current -- that any value previously written by another thread is visible.  The read being atomic is not enough; `volatile` is still necessary to ensure consistency of the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public synchronized int increment()
```

This `synchronized` prevents you from skipping an increment if two threads or more were trying to increment at the same time (because `++` is not atomic).

```
private volatile int value
```

This prevents you from seeing an outdated value in one thread which was already incremented in another thread. (Note that we could also have made getValue synchronized to achieve this)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the answers guys. Found this on oracle website as well now: "Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html